# Google maps api version 1 doesn't work anymore (Android) why?

Tags: android, android-maps, android-maps-v2

I had signed up for Google maps api vesrion 1. I got a key that used to work fine before but now it's not working. On the Official site they said that the applications using google maps version 1 will continue to work, but it is advised not to use it.

So then why doesn't my application work now... I haven't made any changes in the Code.... here is my `log cat`.

```
04-04 16:37:26.701: W/MapActivity(873): Recycling dispatcher android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.datarequest.DataRequestDispatcher@411fc5b0
04-04 16:37:26.801: V/MapActivity(873): Recycling map object.
04-04 16:37:27.321: I/MapActivity(873): Handling network change notification:CONNECTED
04-04 16:37:27.321: E/MapActivity(873): Couldn't get connection factory client
04-04 16:37:32.590: W/System.err(873): IOException processing: 26
04-04 16:37:32.590: W/System.err(873): java.io.IOException: Server returned: 3
04-04 16:37:32.641: W/System.err(873):  at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.map.BaseTileRequest.readResponseData(BaseTileRequest.java:115)
04-04 16:37:32.641: W/System.err(873):  at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.map.MapService$MapTileRequest.readResponseData(MapService.java:1473)
04-04 16:37:32.641: W/System.err(873):  at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.datarequest.DataRequestDispatcher.processDataRequest(DataRequestDispatcher.java:1117)
04-04 16:37:32.641: W/System.err(873):  at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.datarequest.DataRequestDispatcher.serviceRequests(DataRequestDispatcher.java:994)
04-04 16:37:32.641: W/System.err(873):  at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.datarequest.DataRequestDispatcher$DispatcherServer.run(DataRequestDispatcher.java:1702)
04-04 16:37:32.641: W/System.err(873):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
04-04 16:37:38.341: W/System.err(873): IOException processing: 26
04-04 16:37:38.341: W/System.err(873): java.io.IOException: Server returned: 3
04-04 16:37:38.415: W/System.err(873):  at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.map.BaseTileRequest.readResponseData(BaseTileRequest.java:115)
04-04 16:37:38.415: W/System.err(873):  at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.map.MapService$MapTileRequest.readResponseData(MapService.java:1473)
04-04 16:37:38.415: W/System.err(873):  at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.datarequest.DataRequestDispatcher.processDataRequest(DataRequestDispatcher.java:1117)
04-04 16:37:38.421: W/System.err(873):  at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.datarequest.DataRequestDispatcher.serviceRequests(DataRequestDispatcher.java:994)
04-04 16:37:38.421: W/System.err(873):  at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.datarequest.DataRequestDispatcher$DispatcherServer.run(DataRequestDispatcher.java:1702)
04-04 16:37:38.421: W/System.err(873):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
04-04 16:37:45.323: W/System.err(873): IOException processing: 26
04-04 16:37:45.323: W/System.err(873): java.io.IOException: Server returned: 3
04-04 16:37:45.323: W/System.err(873):  at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.map.BaseTileRequest.readResponseData(BaseTileRequest.java:115)
04-04 16:37:45.331: W/System.err(873):  at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.map.MapService$MapTileRequest.readResponseData(MapService.java:1473)
04-04 16:37:45.331: W/System.err(873):  at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.datarequest.DataRequestDispatcher.processDataRequest(DataRequestDispatcher.java:1117)
04-04 16:37:45.331: W/System.err(873):  at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.datarequest.DataRequestDispatcher.serviceRequests(DataRequestDispatcher.java:994)
04-04 16:37:45.331: W/System.err(873):  at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.datarequest.DataRequestDispatcher$DispatcherServer.run(DataRequestDispatcher.java:1702)
04-04 16:37:45.331: W/System.err(873):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
04-04 16:37:51.241: I/Choreographer(873): Skipped 34 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-04 16:37:53.021: W/System.err(873): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Connection pool shut down.
04-04 16:37:53.021: W/System.err(873):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ConnPoolByRoute.getEntryBlocking(ConnPoolByRoute.java:284)
04-04 16:37:53.030: W/System.err(873):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ConnPoolByRoute$1.getPoolEntry(ConnPoolByRoute.java:238)
04-04 16:37:53.030: W/System.err(873):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ThreadSafeClientConnManager$1.getConnection(ThreadSafeClientConnManager.java:176)
04-04 16:37:53.030: W/System.err(873):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:326)
04-04 16:37:53.114: W/System.err(873):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
04-04 16:37:53.114: W/System.err(873):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
04-04 16:37:53.114: W/System.err(873):  at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.common.io.android.AndroidHttpClient.execute(AndroidHttpClient.java:246)
04-04 16:37:53.114: W/System.err(873):  at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.common.io.android.GoogleHttpClient.executeWithoutRewriting(GoogleHttpClient.java:129)
04-04 16:37:53.170: W/System.err(873):  at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.common.io.android.GoogleHttpClient.execute(GoogleHttpClient.java:189)
04-04 16:37:53.200: W/System.err(873):  at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.common.io.android.GoogleHttpClient.execute(GoogleHttpClient.java:242)
04-04 16:37:53.200: W/System.err(873):  at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.common.io.android.AndroidHttpConnectionFactory$AndroidGoogleHttpConnection.getResponse(AndroidHttpConnectionFactory.java:132)
04-04 16:37:53.280: W/System.err(873):  at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.common.io.android.AndroidHttpConnectionFactory$AndroidGoogleHttpConnection.openDataInputStream(AndroidHttpConnectionFactory.java:153)
04-04 16:37:53.280: W/System.err(873):  at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.datarequest.DataRequestDispatcher.serviceRequests(DataRequestDispatcher.java:922)
04-04 16:37:53.280: W/System.err(873):  at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.datarequest.DataRequestDispatcher$DispatcherServer.run(DataRequestDispatcher.java:1702)
04-04 16:37:53.280: W/System.err(873):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Here's my Layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="@string/hello_world"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" />    

<com.google.android.maps.MapView
    android:id="@+id/pooja"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:apiKey="I've used my Key here!!"
    android:clickable="true" />
```

Comment: try generating anew key and then use the same.

Comment: Is there a way today to generate a key for Google Maps API V1?

Comment: Well Version 1 is Now Depricated so they have stopped generating new keys....I had registered long ago so I have a version 1 key

Comment: Now you will get version 2 keys till May 19, 2013 as even that is going to depricate soon, or you can get version 3. But I don't want to migate from version 1 to version 2 or 3 as the method to handle the maps changes drastically please help!!

Comment: Android Google Maps API v2 is not going anywhere. It is just the beginning for this API. Maps JS API v2 will deprecate which has nothing to do with Android. You will have to use Android Google Maps API v2 sooner or later.